# Why does my App window shrink when deployed?

Tags: windows, mfc, dpi

My MFC app written with VS2019 displays correctly at 1920x1080, but when I deploy it to a 1920x1080 laptop it shows up at about 1/4 size. I have toggled DPI Awareness, but without effect.  When I deploy it on a laptop that already has VS2019 on it, it displays correctly.

Comment: What is `about 1/4 size` - text, graphics, dialogs, everything?

Comment: Are they used scaled fonts in the OS settings?

Comment: The only thing i see is the `mfc.dll` version. You say: When I deploy it on a laptop that already has VS2019 on it, it displays correctly ==> This is because installing VS2019 installs a newer version of mfc.dll
You must install the `VCRedistributable` containing an mfc.dll version equivalent to the one installed by VisualStudio 2019

Comment: Please [edit] and show some relevant screenshots, that could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I had been using a font that didn't exist on the target machines.  It is 20 points high, and the default font is 8 points high.  MFC sizes the dialog to fit the font size. All I had to do was copy and install the font file. Thanks for your thoughts and suggestions. For what it is worth,  in the past I  have always used a 3rd party deployment tool that packaged in the fonts, and now I have learned that the Visual Studio supplied tool doesn't do that.

Comment: Nothing to do with MFC, that's just how dialog templates work (see [Dialog Box Measurements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/about-dialog-boxes#dialog-box-measurements)).